# What event is called when you close apps on Nexus 7?

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

I have been trying for hours to get my program to act right, by overriding both `onStop()` and `onDestroy()`, but these event's doesn't seem to fire just right when closing the apps on the Nexus by using the swipe technique like he does in this youtube video http://youtu.be/1HBW7FG-xcQ?t=22s

```
   @Override
     protected void onStop() {
     super.onStop();
     Log.d("onStop", "Yay, we are in!");
     datasource.Open();
     datasource.UpdateIsPlaying(0);
     datasource.Close();
     }

     @Override
      protected void onDestroy() {
      super.onDestroy();
      Log.d("onDestroy", "Yay, we are in!");
      datasource.Open();
      datasource.UpdateIsPlaying(0);
      datasource.Close();
      }

      @Override
       protected void onPause() {
       super.onPause();
       Log.d("onPause", "Yay, we are in!");
       datasource.Open();
       datasource.UpdateIsPlaying(0);
       datasource.Close();
      }
```

Comment: I am running android 4.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you're Overriding correctly those methods?

If the Activity is finished, onDestroy method is triggered. It's impossible not to be triggered if its finished.

What I assume is happening, is that this gesture, isn't finishing the app as it should be finished, or maybe it's just going on background.

Have you tried overriding onPause?

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle

However, if you read Activity documentation:

> There are situations where the system will simply kill the activity's hosting process without calling this method (or any others) in it, so it should not be used to do things that are intended to remain around after the process goes away.

Maybe this gesture clears RAM directly or whatever it does, without following Android standards. I guess that if this is happening, you will have troubles while trying to receive a callback.

Comment: Thanks, tried overriding onPause aswell, did not do the job i have edited the post

Comment: And this just happens when you finish the app with that swipe gesture, right?

Comment: What i hoped to achieve is that when i close my app using the swipe it will fire that event. So that the app has the correct state on next start up.

Comment: But I mean, if you finish it by pressing back button, do the methods get called?

Comment: Yeah it works correctly when i exit it using the back button.

Comment: So as I thought, you've to search for help relating Nexus swipe closing tasks. I can't help you there, as I don't know how it is working.

Comment: Thank you for trying, i have just found a better alternative for a solution. giving u a +1

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with with teh following- place `finish();` from where you want to exit from the app.